# Empty array does not parse when using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin.forms

If requestString is an empty array "[ ]"

This works:

```
JArray.Parse(requestString).ToObject<List<RequestDTO>>();
```

But this doesn't:

```
JArray.Parse(requestString).ToObject<ObservableCollection<RequestDTO>>();
```

Error is: Could not convert string to boolean: Approved. Path '[0].Action', line 1, position 193.'

Moreover, there is no boolean property in RequestDTO.

The RequestDTO object is:

```
public class RequestDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LeaveName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string RequestedOn { get; set; }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: @canton7 I believe it's `[]`.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this issue](https://rextester.com/DKEU42462). What device is this ultimately running on?

Comment: Its being used in Xamarin.Forms application.

Comment: Which platform did you test on and what is the version of Xamarin.Forms?what is the version of Newtonsoft?  I test with latest XF it works fine on iOS , Android ,UWP , no problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks Llama for trying to reproduce. As your code was working fine, I was able to find the issue by further drilling down the execution. The issue was happening because of a binding and not during the parsing itself. I was able to fix by resolving the binding.